# Why do clang++ and gcc/g++ produce differently linked executables

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, clang

When compiling and linking with g++ and clang++ there is an expectation that the resulting executable will be linked equal with respect to their linkage.

However in certain cases it appears that clang++ executables are linked to more libraries than g++ despite the same arguments passed in.

This can cause functional differences especially with respect to dynamically linked libraries that have automatic execution on load and unload.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out gcc has a feature enabled by default in ubuntu `--as-needed` which causes gcc to effectively ignore any library for which none of it's symbols are referenced in the chain of linked items

This can be disabled in gcc with `--no-as-needed` flag. Or alternatively you can issue `-Wl,--as-needed` as the first option to clang++ to behave the way gcc does.

Comment: More precisely, gcc passes `--as-needed` to the *linker*,
causing any *shared* library to be ignored if none of its symbols are referenced in
some file *already linked* when the library is reached. Linkage of objects
from static libraries has always observed this "as-needed" principle, unless overriddden
by `--whole-archive`.